# Blog in Django 1.11 Mapping URLs to Views

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, blogs, django-1.11

I'm new to Django (1.11) and Python(2.7). I'm trying to create a blog. I have a problem wih mapping URLs to views. 
My `myblog\posts\views.py`:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.


def post_home(request):
   return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello</h1")
```

My `myblog\myblog\urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from posts import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^posts/$', posts_view.post_home),
]
```

My `myblog\myblog\settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'posts',
]
```

TypeERROR: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please double check you copy pasted correctly your code. The error you get doesn't make sense with the sample code.

Comment: @Antwane maybe it depends on version of Django. I followed the tutorial of Django 1.9 and there were no error, but I have Django 1.11.

Comment: @Antwane I checked it again. I have the same code. What do you think, what else can be the reason of such error?

Comment: @Antwane when I comment th string `url(r'^posts/$', posts_view.post_home),` in `myblog\myblog\urls.py` everything works.

Comment: The error should be `NameError: name 'posts_view' is not defined`. In your case, you have an error indicating `posts_view.post_home` is not a function. This indicates the module 'posts_view' references something. Unfortunately, in the code you posted, `posts_view` does not refer to anything. Please edit your question and add the code that define or import `posts_view`

Answer (score 1):

There is a few issues in the code you posted:

```
from posts import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^posts/$', posts_view.post_home),
    #                ^^^^^^^^^^
    #                what does this variable refer to ?
]
```

You imported the module (aka: a python file) `posts.views` using statement `from posts import views`, so you have to refer to `post_home` function that way:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # [...]
    url(r'^posts/$', views.post_home),
]
```

That should fix your issue

Note: There is many ways to refer to your view function:

**Example 1**

```
import posts.views
urlpatterns = [
    # [...]
    url(r'^posts/$', posts.views.post_home),
]
```

**Example 2**

```
from posts.views import post_home
urlpatterns = [
    # [...]
    url(r'^posts/$', post_home),
]
```

Comment: I tried both examples but unfortunately it did not solved the problem.

Comment: @nameless does that mean that you get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

Change your import to:

```
from posts.views import post_home
```

and your url to:

```
url(r'^posts/$', post_home),
```

Comment: I changed but it did not solved the problem. I still have the same error.